# Parsing XmlAttribute as complex type

Tags: c#, xml, svg

I'm trying to create object model of SVG format. So, as it XML, i'm using XmlSerializer. But i have a problem. There're some xml attributes named "style". It looks like complex type, but represents as string. There's example of this attribute:

> style="fill:none;stroke:#00ff00;stroke-width:8.7489996;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:8.74900006"

As you can see, there're properties like "fill", "stroke", "stroke-width" and etc.
I wrote the class

```
public class SvgStyle
{
    public string FillColor { get; set; }
    public string StrokeColor { get; set; }
    public float StrokeWidth { get; set; }
    public int StrokeMiterlimit { get; set; }
    public float StrokeOpacity { get; set; }
    public float StrokeDashoffset { get; set; }
    public string StrokeDasharray { get; set; }
}
```

and an another class

```
public abstract class SvgGraphicElement
{
    [XmlAttribute("style")]
    public SvgStyle Style { get; set; }
}
```

All i got is exception

> Cannot serialize member 'Style' of type Svg.SvgStyle. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types.

I tries to use IXmlSerializable interface implemantation and OnSerializing/OnDeserializing methods, but all i got was another exceptions.
Is there any way to deserialize this string to my class?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to implement the IXmlSerializable interface on your SVGStyle class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

Just read that you tried this already; sorry.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlTypes
{
  public class SvgStyle : IXmlSerializable
  {

    private const string fillColorKey = "fill";
    private const string strokeColorKey ="stroke";
    private const string strokeWidthKey = "stroke-width";
    private const string strokeMiterLimitKey = "stroke-miterlimit";
    private const string strokeOpacityKey ="stroke-opacity";
    private const string strokeDashArrayKey="stroke-dasharray";
    private const string strokeDashOffsetKey = "stroke-dashoffset";

    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Style { get; set; }
    public string FillColor { get; set; }
    public string StrokeColor { get; set; }
    public float StrokeWidth { get; set; }
    public int StrokeMiterlimit { get; set; }
    public float StrokeOpacity { get; set; }
    public float StrokeDashoffset { get; set; }
    public string StrokeDasharray { get; set; }


    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
      return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
      reader.MoveToContent();
      Style = reader.GetAttribute("style");
      Dictionary<string, string> lookupTable = ParseAttribute(Style);

      FillColor = lookupTable[fillColorKey];
      StrokeColor = lookupTable[strokeColorKey];

      float strokeWidthFloatValue=0; 
      float.TryParse(lookupTable[strokeWidthKey] , out strokeWidthFloatValue) ;
      StrokeWidth = strokeWidthFloatValue;

      int strokeMiterLimitInt = 0;
      Int32.TryParse(lookupTable[strokeMiterLimitKey] , out strokeMiterLimitInt);
      StrokeMiterlimit = strokeMiterLimitInt;

      int strokeOpacityInt = 0;
      Int32.TryParse(lookupTable[strokeMiterLimitKey], out strokeOpacityInt);
      StrokeOpacity = strokeOpacityInt;

      int strokeDashOffsetInt = 0;
      Int32.TryParse(lookupTable[strokeMiterLimitKey], out strokeDashOffsetInt);
      StrokeDashoffset = strokeDashOffsetInt;

      StrokeDasharray = lookupTable[strokeDashArrayKey];


      Boolean isEmptyElement = reader.IsEmptyElement; // (1)
      reader.ReadStartElement();

    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
      writer.WriteAttributeString("style", Style);

    }
    private Dictionary<string, string> ParseAttribute(string attribute)
    {
      string[] arr = attribute.Split(';');
      Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
      {
        string[] arrItem = arr[i].Split(':');
        dic.Add(arrItem[0], arrItem[1]);
      }
      return dic;
    }    
  }
}





 [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
      string xml = @"<SvgStyle style='fill:none;stroke:#00ff00;stroke-width:8.7489996;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:8.74900006'></SvgStyle>";

      XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SvgStyle));
      SvgStyle myTest = (SvgStyle)x.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));

    }
```

Comment: Implementing IXmlSerializable interface gives me another exception "Cannot serialize member 'Style' of type Svg.SvgStyle. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode types implementing IXmlSerializable". So, can you give more details how I shoud implement it? I set all attributes on class and it's properties like in this example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635582/how-to-use-a-custom-ixmlserializable-as-an-xmlattribute).

Comment: In your example you merge two different entities, in my case SvgGraphicElement and SvgStyle. Maybe it was my mistake in question, but "style" is attribute of SvgGraphicElement, and there's no SvgStyle element. At the moment it looks like i need to implement IXmlSerializable interfase for SvgGraphicElement class, but not SvgStyle.

Comment: Can you provide the xml?

Comment: This is sample xml:
`<svg id="svg2">
  <defs id="defs4" />
  <metadata id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g id="layer1">
    <rect width="497" height="177" id="rect2985" style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:54;stroke-miterlimit:51;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:50" />
  </g>
</svg>`