# Deserialize List Error

Tags: c#, xml, exception, xml-serialization, deserialization

I have an XML and the content is

```
<Contracts>
    <Contract EntryType="U" ID="401" GroupCode="1">
    </Contract>
</Contracts>
```

and I have a class with a list of contracts

```
[XmlArray("Contracts")]
[XmlArrayItem("Contract", typeof(Contract))]
public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
```

so when I try to Deserialize this, I got this error:

> "There was an error reflecting property 'Contracts'."

Deserialization code:

```
XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContractPosting));
xml.Position = 0;
eContractXML = (Contract)reader.Deserialize(xml);
```

Here are the classes:

```
public partial class ContractPosting
{
    [XmlArray("Contracts")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Contract", typeof(Contract))]
    public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ContractID")]
    public System.Nullable<int> ContractID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName= "PostingID")]
    public string PostingID { get; set; }

    public EntryTypeOptions? EntryType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the `InnerException`, you will get a more detailed error message explaining why it couldn't deserialize.

Comment: Could you paste in the definition of the class? public class Contract {}...etc.

Comment: What is the `type` you want to deserialize? Which serializer do you use?

Comment: public partial class ContractPosting {
  [XmlArray("Contracts")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Contract", typeof(Contract))]
  public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
  
 }


 public class Contract {
 [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ContractID")]
 public System.Nullable<int> ContractID { get; set; }

 [XmlAttribute(AttributeName= "PostingID")]
 public string PostingID { get; set; }

 public System.Nullable<EntryTypeOptions> EntryType { get; set; }

 }

Comment: The error is with the `Contract` class.  Please edit your question to show this class and the inner exceptions.

Comment: {"There was an error reflecting property 'Contracts'."}
    [System.InvalidOperationException]: {"There was an error reflecting property 'Contracts'."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"There was an error reflecting type 'Entity.Contract'."}
    Message: "There was an error reflecting property 'Contracts'."

Comment: Source: "System.Xml"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)\r\n   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)\r\n

Comment: at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)"
    TargetSite: {Boolean InitializeStructMembers(System.Xml.Serialization.StructMapping, System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel, Boolean, System.String, System.Xml.Serialization.RecursionLimiter)}

Comment: I tested your code, and when I went down to the bottom-most InnerException (4 levels deep), I found this error message: `Cannot serialize member 'ContractID' of type System.Nullable``1[System.Int32]. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types.` - which is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074240/serializing-a-nullabledatetime-in-to-xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nullable types cannot be serialised as attributes.

You must either change the `Contract` class to not use `Nullable` for the XML attributes or change the XML to write these properties as an XML element.

Try this:

```
public class Contract { 
  [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ContractID")] 
  public int ContractID { get; set; } 

  [XmlAttribute(AttributeName= "PostingID")] 
  public string PostingID { get; set; } 

  public System.Nullable<EntryTypeOptions> EntryType { get; set; } 
}
```

OR:

```
public class Contract { 
  public int? ContractID { get; set; } 

  [XmlAttribute(AttributeName= "PostingID")] 
  public string PostingID { get; set; } 

  public System.Nullable<EntryTypeOptions> EntryType { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the root node is `<Contracts>`, try re-arranging your class to this:

```
[XmlRoot("Contracts")]
public class ContractPosting {
    [XmlElement("Contract", typeof(Contract))]
    public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

When you use `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem`, they have to both be nested inside of something.  But your current `XmlArray` tag is actually the root node of the `XML` file, so it needs to be an `XmlRoot`.

Demo: http://ideone.com/jBSwGx

Comment: Change the `Nullable<int>` to a regular `int` for `ContractID`, or convert it to an element instead of an attribute, and then it should work - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074240/serializing-a-nullabledatetime-in-to-xml

Answer (score 0):

thanks, the problem was the Nullable type and I solved in this way

```
[XmlIgnore]
public System.Nullable<int> ContractID { get; set; }


[XmlAttribute("ContractID")]
public int ContractIDxml {
get { return ContractID ?? 00; }
set { ContractID = value; }
}
```